# In Python Use Current Directory as variable

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

I want to use my current directory inside my fout = file statement. The timestamp variable works fine but i have to manually enter the directory to get that part to work and i would like it to be automatic.

```
dir = os.getcwd()
timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I-%M%p")
qs = self.rfile.read(int(length[0]))
fout = file(os.path.join('/dir', 'video_'+timeStamp+'_.mov'), 'wb')
fout.write (qs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
dir = os.getcwd()
timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I-%M%p")
os.path.join('/dir', 'video_'+timeStamp+'_.mov')
```

and seem to be puzzled as to why you are getting something like `/dir/video…` out of the os.path.join(). You have quoted `/dir` so are literally getting `'/dir'` in your pathname. If you instead used:

```
os.path.join(dir, 'video…')
```

Youd get the cwd concatenated with the rest of the file name.

Comment: the script will not run if i do not put the '/dir' around the directory, it seems to need a exact string.

Comment: "will not run". What happens? Do you get an error? If so, what error where? So long as you have `/dir` in quotes, you will never get the value of `os.getcwd()` added to your string.

Comment: I get this error.  File "web.py", line 32
   fout = file(os.path.join(/dir, 'video_'+timeStamp+'_.mov'), 'wb') 
                                       ^   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There is a little carrot pointing to /dir for the invalid syntax.

Comment: `/dir` is not a syntactically valid variable name, `dir` is. Of course Python is complaining about syntax; drop the slash and you should be fine.